# Access 365 VBA "On Error" not suppressing "Item not found in this collection."

Tags: vba, ms-access, error-handling, office365

My program wants to delete a table IF IT EXISTS. This neat little function (courtesy Terry Kreft) used to work every time, but today, under Access 365, it fails with "Item not found in this collection."

```
 Function TableExists(Tablename As String) As Boolean
    Dim loTab As DAO.TableDef
    On Error Resume Next
    Set loTab = CurrentDb.TableDefs(Tablename)  <<<< This is where the error occurs
    TableExists = (Err = 0)
 End Function
```

`
Now in this case the table definitely DOES NOT EXIST, so the error message is correct - but surely it should not be output following the "On Error"

I would be grateful for any help!

Comment: Check your settings in the VBE (Visual Basic Editor): Tools->Options, on the "General" Tab: What is the setting of "Error Trapping": If it is set to "Break on all Errors", the runtime will always stop if an error occurs (independently of the On Error-statements). Good for debugging, not so good if you deal with an "expected" error

Answer (score 0):

Sorry - I am a twit!
I had  VBA Tools | Options | General "Break on all errors" set. Flipped to "Break on unhandled errors" and now everything works.